# search logic on android

Tags: android, search

I'm new to android and i followed the documentation on https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#UsingSearchWidget to implement search, I am using a search widget. My problem is I am absolutely clueless on how to implement the doMySearch(String query) method. I am searching on a list returned from a service. How do i go about doing it?
This is what i have on my searchableActivity so far.

```
    private ConsultantListAdapter consultantList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Get the intent, verify the action and get the query
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            doMySearch(query);
    }

}
    private void doMySearch(String query) {

    }
```

Comment: study about this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.OnQueryTextListener.html

Comment: Thank you, but i need to see a basic example of how this could be done.